# How to export data from onLoad function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest, return-value, onload

Open, onload and send are sub-function of XMLHttpRequest. How can i access dataOrder value from outside of onLoad function ?

```
    var dataOrder;
    ourRequestLimitOrder1h.open('GET', urlLimitOrder1h, true);
    ourRequestLimitOrder1h.onload = function () {
        const jSonObjeOrder = 
    JSON.parse(ourRequestLimitOrder1h.responseText);
           dataOrder = jSonObjeOrder.data[0][3];

    };
    ourRequestLimitOrder1h.send();
    console.log(dataOrder);
```

Comment: Why do you need to access `dataOrder` outside of `load` event handler?

Comment: I need to handle dataOrder another function. After, another function sends the different function using POST method

Comment: See [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/)